# Intel SSB temperature sensor

Tags: intel, hardware, physical-environment

I have an Intel server motherboard that is reporting an issue with the SSB temperature sensor.

I have searched for the acronym but cannot find a definition. What does SSB stand for?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just the server board/mobo.  Sounds like the temp sensor on the board itself is reporting an issue.

Comment: Some extracts from a manual that may help you find the answer: *the BMC initializes this internal clock to the value retrieved from the SSB component’s RTC* and *NM is supported only on platforms that have the NM FW functionality loaded and enabled on the Management Engine (ME) in the SSB*

Answer (score 1):

That would be "server south bridge", according to Intel: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/s2600xxv3_errata_02242015_final.pdf (search for SSB)

Answer (score 0):

If you have something similiar to Intel® Server Board S2600CO Family
TPS 
[Specs PDF here](http://cache-www.intel.com/cd/00/00/49/64/496485_496485.pdf)
this might be the shortform of "single-sideband modulation"

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sideband_modulation) for details